# Which preposition is better in “get down (off / from) something”, off or from?

Tags: word-choice, prepositions

Consider these two possibilities:

1. A cat couldn't get down **off** the tree in the parking lot.
2. A cat couldn't get down **from** the tree in the parking lot.

It seems like *from* fits better. But what about *off*, though?

I don’t know whether it’s relevant to this particular case, but I often associate *off* with sentences with undesired objects, like here:

3. Get the cat **off** the Christmas tree!
4. Get your feet **off** the table!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*Down from* and *down off* can and do overlap, but they are not always used in the
same ways.  They are not freely interchangeable in all cases, and it’s only how common each different type of use is that determines overall frequency.

In the case of people in a tree, or cats, you get **down *from*** it because you got **up *into*** it and not, presumably, **up on top** of it. Angels sit upon the top of a Christmas tree, but real people do not. They’re only **in** it, not **on** it.

When followed by a deictic like *here* or *there*, then *down from
here/there* is about twenty times more frequent in the Corpus of American English (COCA) than *down off
here/there* is.  However, no other case than this one presents so high a ratio of one compared to the other.

**In general**, the ratio tends to be about
half again as many with *down from* as you find from *down off*. But this
can be easily explained because the situations that lead to *down off* are
less common than those that lead to *down from*.  It’s not a popularity
contest. You can’t just count up instances divorced of context.

First and most importantly, *down off* and *up on* are opposites. You get
down off from somewhere or something **that you’re up *on top of***, whether literally or figuratively.  This
includes mountains, soap boxes, high horses, and crosses.

Some examples of *down off* from COCA are:

- I suggest you get down off your high horse there.
- The bay doors whined like a pair of old dogs asked to get down off the sofa.
- We just need to get down off the car.
- Get down off the cross, honey. Somebody needs the wood.
- Just call me when you get down off the mountain.
- Get down off that Wall. Now.
- She had to get down off this roof.
- Get down off that wagon right now, or I will shoot you where you sit.
- Oh dear. Sorry I will get down off of my soap box.
- As a token Libertarian here, I’ll get down off my high horse and comment that...
- Get down off of this fence right now!
- Get down. Munn, shut up. Carver, get down off the table right now. Get down. Get off the table right now.
- Me, I’ve got ta get down off my mountain top and join the real world.
- Get down off of my car, please. And get up on the sidewalk.
- If you’d get down off your high horse you’d start to appreciate Julian.
- Now, you know, when I get down off the golf course, you know, I see this little boy who’s...

In contrast, you get **down *from*** something that you’re just **up in**,
not something you’re **up upon**. See the difference? So if you’ve climbed
up into a tree, then you are not atop the tree so you don’t get down off
it; you get down from it.

Here are some COCA examples of *down from*:

- Uh Julia, get down from the pulpit, I don’t need your history lesson.
- Norman! Get down from there this instant! You’re supposed to be grounded!
- It’s time to get down from the pedestals that make everyone feel "Pure and Perfect" and move on.
- Get down from that tree now! Got bad spirits up there.
- Get off the bleachers or you will be arrested! I repeat. Get down from the bleachers or you will be arrested!
- Harry, get down from the table this instant!
- Do you mind if we get down from here?
- And as they would get down from the vehicles, I would go up and talk to them.
- ... with a playfully chivalrous gesture, he helped her get down from the tall stool and escorted her to the door.
- You need to get down from the altar and take a cold shower.
- Baby Huey show Shakespeare how we get down from the victory tower!
- ... "Danger from the ground!", "Get down from the trees", "Get up into the trees", etc., ...
- He watched Raymond get down from the new porch and walk in the growing daylight straight to the pickup.

Answer (score 0):

[Per Ngram viewer](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=get+down+off+the%2Cget+down+from+the&year_start=1800&year_end=2019&corpus=en-2019&smoothing=3), both "off" and "from" are common after "get down," but "from" is the more popular choice.